# Cannot stop images from dropping below content when hovering over it

Tags: html, css

The issue I am facing is that when hovering on the top image element the bottom image element is being forced down the page. I want the top image element to go over the bottom image element without forcing the bottom image element down the page.

Any input would be helpful

Thanks!

[output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oKbW.png)

```css
<style>

.image-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.image-box img { width: 215px; height: 150px; }

.grow {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 160px;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}
.grow:hover {
  height: 245px;
  margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  
}


</style>
```

```html
<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>
<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>
```

**Problem**

When hovering over top image element, the images below drop further down the page ( as shown in diagram )

How can I get the above image element to go over the top of the bottom element without forcing the bottom element further down the page

Answer (score 1):

Using a negative margin on grow:hover to account for the change in height should fix your problem (original height + bottom margin - expanded height = -80px) as well as z-index to make sure it is actually on top. You'll also need to change your transition to include margin to handle both changes smoothly and make your boxes inline-block instead of float left as this causes some jerkiness:

```css
<style>

.image-box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.image-box img { width: 215px; height: 150px; }

.grow {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 160px;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: height 0.5s, margin 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.5s, margin 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grow:hover {
  height: 245px;
  margin: 5px 1% -80px 1%;
  z-index:9;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>
<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem, I needed to apply a negative margin

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```css
.image-box img { width: 215px; height: 150px; }

.grow {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 160px;
  width: 230px;
  margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.grow p{
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  z-index:55;
  transition: top 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
}
.grow:hover p{ 
  top:170px;
  left:999;
  z-index:9999;
  margin: 5px 1% 5px 1%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>
<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>

<div class="image-box grow">
<a href=""><img src="img/never.png" ><p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature</p></a>
</div>
```